# jsonp, json, jquery, ajax and wordpress refresh page ! :S

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, redirect, jsonp

Hi i have two wordpress sites where i want to make some ajax jsonp data transfers between them.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "http://www.testsite.com/",  
        data: {test1:'<?php echo $_REQUEST['test1'] ?>',test2:'<?php echo $_REQUEST['test2'] ?>'}, 
        crossDomain: true, 
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function() {  
            <?php
            header("Location: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); //refresh
            ?>

        }
        return false;  
    });

</script>
```

And it does not work with

```
header("Location: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); //refresh
```

This line. 
It seems that i does not run the ajax/jsonp request at all , nothing happens, nothing works.

**But if i remove this line it works as expected!!!**

Since i really need this line (to reload page), i dont know what to do ? any ideas how to overcome this (how to run ajax script completely and then refresh site)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is server side, JavaScript is client side.

You cannot execute PHP with JavaScript.

Instead use `window.location` of JavaScript. Doc: http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php